# How to insert multiple asp.net checkboxes values to MSSQl database as comma seperaed string 1,2,3,4,5 using vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, vb.net

How to insert and retrive multiple asp.net checkboxes values to MSSQl database as comma seperaed string 1,2,3,4,5 using vb.net ?

and retrieve the inserted checkbox chekched in disabled form ..using vb.net

example of this is :

http://www.redbus.in/Booking/SeatSelection.aspx?rt=4017230&doj=31-Dec-2010&dep=04:55%20PM&showSpInst=false

I want this type of whole layout in vb.net ... means if user registered selected seats then then next the same page load for todays date the selected seats will be disabled ...

pleas provide me the code snippet for that // insert and retrieve funda... in checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with such a loop

```
 string str = "";
            for (int i = 0; i <= 29; i++)
            {
                if (CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Selected)
                {
                    string b = CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Value;
                    str += b + " , ";
                }

            }
```

than make an insert statement and you are putting all the checkbox values into a column.
than just call select statement call the column

Comment: I dont wanna use checkboxlist i wanna use checkbox... this coding i already know.... sorry

Comment: Try to add all checkbox values into a listitem than use a foreach

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a very bad thing storing lists of values in a single MSSQL column.  I know it may be convenient now, but it is always eventually bad news.  Why not store booked seats in their own table, one seat per row?  When you store a list of values in a column, you restrict access to the information stored in that column to only the code that can split the list.  It isn't available to database queries or to other code as a list, merely as a string.  You will end up replicating the code to split this string to other places that need the list data.